# Css stops working when I add a class of a checkbox's label

Tags: html, css

I'm really sorry, I know this is a very basic question.

The code works fine, except if I try to apply the attribute to another object, in this case a label. class "c". I don't understand why such a basic thing is not working.

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" id="boton" disabled>hi</button>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checky"/>
 <label class="c" id="checkyl" for="checky">etiquette</label>
```

CSS:

```
#boton:disabled:hover + .c {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Isn't "+" for immediately after?  (There's in input in-between the elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the general sibling selector `~`

```css
#boton:disabled:hover~.c {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="boton" disabled>hi</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="checky" />
<label class="c" id="checkyl" for="checky">etiquette</label>
```

The adjacent sibling selector `+` won't work in this case because `.c` does not come directly after `#boton`

Comment: I thought that + was for a specific element and ~ for elements inside the one being used. Thank you, you've been really kind.

Comment: No problem. You should have a look here for a fun little game based on CSS selectors https://flukeout.github.io/#

Answer (score 2):

```
.c1 + .c2 {
  /* styles here  */
}
```

the above selector selects element with class c2 which is just after the element with class .c1

```
.c1 ~ .c2 {
  /* styles here  */
}
```

This selector selects element with class c2 which is sibling if the element with class .c1

In your case you need to use sibling(~) selector instead of adjacent-sibling(+) selector

```
#boton:disabled:hover~.c {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```